# next js Image not updating

Tags: next.js

in next js i have an image in the public folder and it is being displayed using  component and there is a button that when i click, it will change the image in the public folder but with the same path, filename and extention and now when i refresh the page the image is not updating to the new image and still display the old one.

code :

```
const mainImage: string = row.getValue("mainImage");
    return (
      <div className="w-full flex items-center justify-center">
        <Image src={`${mainImage}`}  width={60} height={60} className="rounded" alt={row.getValue("title")} priority={true} />
      </div>
    );
```

tried setting the key to Date.now() but it didn't working.
i asked chatgpt and it suggested setting the source to :
src={`/path/to/image.jpg?version=${new Date().getTime()}`} and it worked but in the every time i refresh the server console shows this error :
upstream image response failed for /products/2/mainImage/mainImage_0.png?version=1705742307786 ResponseAborted. although i really work.

Comment: Edit your question by including the button that changes the image